# BigQuery Table creation options

Tags: google-bigquery

When we create a table under a particular dataset, we have 5 options like empty table , Google cloud storage and upload etc.My question is if it is a Cloud storage , where does this table gets created in BigQuery or Cloud storage ? as my intention is to dump the data in cloud storage and then load in to BigQuer. Same goes for empty table also as we explicitly define schema , I understand the table will reside in BQ.
[image]
I have load the data by below script:

bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --autodetect --ignore_unknown_values \
commerce.balltoball gs://balltoballbucket/head_usa_names.csv

I suppose the balltoballbucket is referred to storage bucket where as commerce.balltoball is BigQuery refrence.

Apologies for newbie question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `bq load` works, then UI should work for you. The documentation is here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table (then pick `Console` tab)

- Select file from GCS bucket: gs://balltoballbucket/head_usa_names.csv
- File Format: CSV
- Dataset Name: commerce
- Table Name: balltoball
- Other options see on the page:

> (Optional) Click Advanced options.

As to where the table is stored, if you pick `Native table` as Table type, it is stored inside BigQuery storage, and `External table` for letting the data stay on GCS and only read from GCS when there is a query hitting the table.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Zhang, it works but but my question is where does this table get stored in Storage or BigQuery.

Comment: Updated with a picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Zhang. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please accept the answer and/or upvote if you find it helpful :)